# Perl regular expression removing duplicate consecutive substrings in a string

Tags: regex, perl, substring

I tried to do a search on this particular problem, but all I get is either removal of duplicate lines or removal of repeated strings where they are separated by a delimiter.

My problem is slightly different. I have a string such as

```
    "comp name1 comp name2 comp name2 comp name3"
```

where I want to remove the repeated comp name2 and return only

```
    "comp name1 comp name2 comp name3"
```

They are not consecutive duplicate words, but consecutive duplicate substrings. Is there a way to solve this using regular expressions?

Comment: what if you have ` "comp name1 comp name2 comp name2 comp name3 comp name4 comp name2"`  ? what will be the output?

Comment: Hi @kurumi, I am only interested in consecutive repeats only. So, the second (or the third in the input) comp name2 will be intact.

Comment: Does it have to be regular expressions? String methods would be better for this IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
s/(.*)\1/$1/g
```

Be warned that the running time of this regular expression is quadratic in the length of the string.

Comment: I am aware of the time complexity. In my case these are fairly short strings (~100 chars max) and would not take that long.

Comment: @btilly : how about the same problem with lines and not strings????.. If i have consecutive duplicate lines??

Comment: @unkaitha: `perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++' file.txt > no_dupe_lines.txt`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (MacOS X 10.6.7, Perl 5.13.4):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = "comp name1 comp name2 comp name2 comp name3" ;
my $output = "comp name1 comp name2 comp name3" ;

my $result = $input;
$result =~ s/(.*)\1/$1/g;

print "In:   <<$input>>\n";
print "Want: <<$output>>\n";
print "Got:  <<$result>>\n";
```

The key point is the '\1' in the matching.

Comment: Slight variation of @btilly's solution. Thanks, but will have to go with the other as he was first.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid removing duplicate characters *within* the terms (e.g. comm1 -> com1) bracket .* in regular expression with \b.

```
s/(\b.*\b)\1/$1/g
```

Answer (score 1):

I never work with languages that support this but since you are using Perl ...

Go here .. and [see this section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)....

Useful Example: Checking for Doubled Words

When editing text, doubled words such as "the the" easily creep in. Using the regex \b(\w+)\s+\1\b  in your text editor, you can easily find them. To delete the second word, simply type in \1 as the replacement text and click the Replace button.

Comment: Please, please, please.  Don't call the language "pearl".  It is "Perl" and the executable is "perl".

Comment: @btilly: fixed for him - I agree 100%.  Also, the question is not about simple 'doubled words'; it is about 'doubled phrases' where the phrase might consist of more than one word.  The answer you give can be extended to get to the required answer, but ...

Comment: I found this in my searches, but it is only for repeated words and not strings. My substrings have word boundaries in them so this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I should have used "double phrases" instead of substrings.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something running in linear time, you could `split` the string and iterate through the list:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                       

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "comp name1 comp name2 comp name2 comp name3";
my @elems = split("\\s", $str);
my $prevComp;
my $prevFlag = -1;
foreach my $elemIdx (0..(scalar @elems - 1)) {
    if ($elemIdx % 2 == 1) {
        if (defined $prevComp) {
            if ($prevComp ne $elems[$elemIdx]) {
                print " $elems[$elemIdx]";
                $prevFlag = 0;
            }
            else {
                $prevFlag = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            print " $elems[$elemIdx]";
        }
        $prevComp = $elems[$elemIdx];
    }
    elsif ($prevFlag == -1) {
        print "$elems[$elemIdx]";
        $prevFlag = 0;
    }
    elsif ($prevFlag == 0) {
        print " $elems[$elemIdx]";
    }
}
print "\n";
```

Dirty, perhaps, but should run faster.